# storing binary data on cassandra just like MYSQL BLOB binary

Tags: database, nosql, cassandra

can we store binary data to apache cassandra?

i'm thinking about storing image to apache cassandra

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Cassandra's public API is based on Thrift, which offers no streaming abilities -- any value written or fetched has to fit in memory. This is inherent to Thrift's design and is therefore unlikely to change. So adding large object support to Cassandra would need a special API that manually split the large objects up into pieces. A potential approach is described in http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-265. As a workaround in the meantime, you can manually split files into chunks of whatever size you are comfortable with -- at least one person is using 64MB -- and making a file correspond to a row, with the chunks as column values. "

From: [CassandraLimitations](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations)

Answer (score 4):

it depends on the size, cassandra is not suitable for large binary objects, it can store up to 2gb by each column splitted into 1 mb. you can store the files in filesystem (or a cdn for web) and store the links and maybe with previews to cassandra, or you can take a look at mongodb+gridfs.